# A simple Artinian left quotient ring of a left Noetherian domain

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian, division-algebras, artinian

Recall the following known result, [Theorem 6.1](http://www.users.miamioh.edu/keelerds/706/goldie.pdf): A ring $R$ is a prime left Goldie ring if and only if $R$ has a left quotient ring which is a matrix ring over a division ring (= simple Artinian).

Now, let $R$ be an infinite dimensional $k$-algebra, which is a left Noetherian domain (a special case of prime left Goldie), $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
By the above result $R$ has a left quotient ring which is a matrix ring over a division ring, $M_n(D)$ ($D$ is infinite dimensional over $k$).

> Is it possible to find $n$ and $D$? If this question is too general, then let us consider the special case $R=A_1(\mathbb{C})$, the [first Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) over $\mathbb{C}$. **Edit:** I have found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233097523_The_skew_field_of_fractions_of_the_Weyl_algebra_contains_a_free_noncommutative_subalgebra) by Makar-Limanov (I have not succeeded to download it), which mentions that the ring of quotients of the first Weyl algebra is a division ring, so in this case $n=1$.

Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258694/simple-artinian-ring-s-is-isomorphic-to-a-matrix-ring-over-a-division-ring) relevant question.

Any hints and comments are welcome.