# The ring of quotients of the first Weyl algebra

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, noetherian, division-algebras, artinian

Since there are no comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292529/a-simple-artinian-left-quotient-ring-of-a-left-noetherian-domain), I now restrict it to the following question:

It is known that: A ring $R$ is a prime left Goldie ring if and only if $R$ has a left quotient ring which is a matrix ring over a division ring (= simple Artinian); see, for example, [Theorem 6.1](http://www.users.miamioh.edu/keelerds/706/goldie.pdf).

Take $R=A_1(\mathbb{C})$, the first Weyl algebra over $\mathbb{C}$;
it is a Noetherian domain, hence the above theorem can be applied, and we get that its left ring of quotients, denote it by $S$, is (isomorphic to) $M_n(D)$, $D$ a division algebra (infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$).

[Makar-Limanov](http:////www.researchgate.net/publication/233097523_The_skew_field_of_fractions_of_the_Weyl_algebra_contains_a_free_noncommutative_subalgebra) (I could not download his article) mentions that $S$ is a division ring, so this means (if I am not wrong) that $n=1$.

> (1) How to show that $n=1$? An available reference will help.
>
> (2) From [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258694/simple-artinian-ring-s-is-isomorphic-to-a-matrix-ring-over-a-division-ring), $D$ is the algebra of $S$-homomorphisms of a minimal nonzero left ideal of $S$; Can one describe $D$ more 'accurately'? (in terms of the generators $x$ and $y$ of $R$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: If $R$ is a domain then so is the left ring of quotients of $R$, but $M_n(D)$ is only a domain when $n=1$. This should answer (1) unless I am missing something?

Comment: You are right. I missed the claim that the left ring of quotients of a domain is a domain. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Here is a reference for the claim that a left Noetherian domain is a left Ore domain and the left quotient ring of a left Ore domain is a division ring:https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/ore-domains-1-2/