# The division ring of fractions of the first Weyl algebra and its subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras, division-ring

The [first Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra),
$A_1(k)= k\langle x,y | yx-xy=1\rangle$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero, is known to be a simple Noetherian ring, hence it has a (left) division ring of fractions (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294023/the-ring-of-quotients-of-the-first-weyl-algebra)), denote it by $D_{x,y}$.

Let $f:A_1(k) \to A_1(k)$ be a $k$-algebra endomorphism (by simplicity, it is necessarily injective. In 1968, Dixmier conjectured that $f$ must be surjective).
Denote $p:=f(x)$ and $q:=f(y)$. The image of $A_1(k)$ under $f$,
$k\langle p,q | qp-pq=1\rangle$, is isomorphic to $A_1(k)$, so it also has its own (left) division ring of fractions, denote it by $D_{p,q}$. Clearly,
$D_{p,q} \subseteq D_{x,y}$.

Please, I have two questions:

> (1) Is it true that every element of $D_{x,y}$ is of the form $b^{-1}a$, where $0 \neq b,a \in A_1(k)$? I think that the answer is trivially yes.

$D_{x,y}$ is a free left $D_{p,q}$-module, and $D_{p,q}$ has the IBN property,
so the rank of $D_{p,q} \subseteq D_{x,y}$ is well-defined (in analogy to the dimension of a field extension);
see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424025/dimension-of-division-rings-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1).

> (2) Is the rank of $D_{p,q} \subseteq D_{x,y}$ finite or infinite?

If I am not wrong, the rank is necessarily $\leq \aleph_0$ (since probably a subset of $x^iy^j$ can serve as a basis?). 
In analogy: If $f:k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ has an invertible Jacobian, then [Keller's theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183549636) (Theorem 2.1, birational case) says that if $k(p,q)=k(x,y)$ then $k[p,q]=k[x,y]$, namely such $f$ is surjective, hence an automorphism (surjective iff bijective, in a Noetherian ring). In the commutative case, $k(p,q) \subseteq k(x,y)$ is finite dimensional.

> My suspecture: Similarly to Keller's theorem for polynomial rings,
>   here we also have: If $D_{p,q}=D_{x,y}$, then $f$ is surjective (so the Dixmier Conjecture is true if the division rings are equal).

I wonder if it is less difficult to show an equality of the division rings,
$D_{p,q}=D_{x,y}$, than to show an equality of the fields of fractions, $k(p,q)=k(x,y)$.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, things tend to get harder, not easier, when commutativity is removed.